# Rackunit: in-depth check of exception type

Tags: unit-testing, exception, racket, rackunit

In Rackunit, I know how to assert that an exception is thrown:

```
#lang racket

(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  (check-exn exn:fail:contract? (lambda () (3 + 4))))
```

However, I cannot find a way to assert something more specific. Looking [at the exception hierarchy in Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._exn~3afail~3acontract%29%29), `exn:fail:contract` could mean a number of things: a wrong arity, a division by zero ...

I would like to assert in the test that this particular exception is one that reads:

```
; application: not a procedure;
;  expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
```

in its printed message. How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The predicate doesn't have to be a built-in exception predicate. You can use your own, like this:

```
(check-exn (lambda (e)
             (and (exn:fail:contract? e)
                  (regexp-match #rx"not a procedure" (exn-message e))))
           (lambda () (3 + 4)))
```

Rackunit's [`check-exn`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._check-exn%29%29) also accepts a regexp in place of an exception predicate. In that case, it checks for an `exn:fail` (or any of its subtypes) whose message matches the regexp. So you could also write this:

```
(check-exn #rx"not a procedure" (lambda () (3 + 4)))
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!